# Validatecommand is called when I edit the entry programmatically

Tags: python, validation, tkinter

I am trying to create an entry with a very special validation. For that, I'm playing dirty with validatecommand. However, I got a problem:

When something in the entry is deleted, I can't tell if it was done with the delete or backspace key (and tutorial pages like this: https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-validation/ no substitution is indicated provide that information).

So, I decided to add a bind. The function that I link returns "break" and must take care of removing a character and inserting a space in its place.

The problem, as the title says, is that validatecommand even validates entry edits made with the insert and delete methods.

To avoid this I considered disabling validation (which always returns True) while I make the corresponding edits. But this could cause other entries not to be validated.

Is there a way to skip that validation when programmatically editing an entry?

I leave you this code so that you have some basis to help me:

```
from functools import partial

class ChrFormat:
    def __init__(self):
        self.charvalidators = []

    def register_in(self, widget):
        widget.config(validate="key", validatecommand=(widget.register(partial(self, widget)), "%d", "%i", "%P", "%s", "%S"))

    def add(self, obj):
        self.charvalidators.append(obj)

    def __call__(self, widget, accion, index, new_text, old_text, char):
        accion = int(accion)
        index = int(index)
        
        if(len(char) == 1):
            if(accion == 1):
                if(index < self.width):
                    for validator in self.charvalidators[index:]:
                        if(not isinstance(validator, str)):
                            break
                        index += 1
                    else:
                        return False

                    if(validator(char)):
                        widget.delete(index)
                        widget.insert(index, char)
                        widget.icursor(index + 1)

        return (accion != 1)

    def apply(self):
        self.width = len(self.charvalidators)
        self.null = "".join((part if(isinstance(part, str)) else " ") for part in self.charvalidators)

fecha = ChrFormat()
fecha.add(str.isdecimal)
fecha.add(str.isdecimal)
fecha.add("-")
fecha.add(str.isdecimal)
fecha.add(str.isdecimal)
fecha.add("-")
fecha.add(str.isdecimal)
fecha.add(str.isdecimal)
fecha.add(str.isdecimal)
fecha.add(str.isdecimal)
fecha.apply()

from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

sv = tk.StringVar()

entrada = ttk.Entry(textvariable=sv)
entrada.pack()

fecha.register_in(entrada)

sv.set(fecha.null)
```

I think I didn't explain myself well, sorry. What I'm looking for is that when the user presses backspace, it deletes a number and puts a space in its place. And something similar with delete. But I need to know which side of the cursor to put that space on.

Obviously, natural validation is the right thing for this, maybe do the validation through binds.

For those who know a bit about Clipper programming languaje, I want to mimic what happens when a picture is placed, such as `'@r 999.999'`. I would post a video, but I'm not in a good time to record and I didn't find any videos to prove it.

Comment: Why do you need to disable the validation when programmatically modifying the entry widget? You should be modifying it in a way that passes the validation step.

Comment: @BryanOakley Because I want it to let me put a space where the user can only type numbers.

Comment: So, you want to make the entry invalid but not have it flagged as invalid?

Comment: What I want to do is let me enter the space programmatically without validating it.

Comment: @BryanOakley I made an edit to the question. I hope it will help you better understand my goal.

Comment: I understand. You're in effect wanting to let the user make an invalid edit. You want them to press the backspace key which inserts a space. That space makes the data invalid but you don't care.

Comment: Exactly Bryan Oakley!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to skip that validation when programmatically editing an entry?

The simplest solution is to set the `validate` option to "none" before making the edits. You then can turn the validation back on via `after_idle` as documented in the [official tk documentation](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6.11/TkCmd/entry.htm#M16)

```
widget.configure(validate="none")
widget.delete(index)
widget.insert(index, char)
widget.icursor(index + 1)
widget.after_idle(lambda: widget.configure(validate="key"))
```

Comment: Thank you Brian Oakley! In the end I decided to take a different approach: Bind the "<Key>" event to a function and return "break" when needed. Still, I'll accept your answer!